# Hibernate Mapping Entities for Different Requirement

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have two entities. 1) Document and 2) Document_Users. A document can have readers and writers. Tables are designed as below:

**Document**

- Id
- name

**Document_Users**

- id
- name
- role
- document_id

"role" attribute can have value either READER and WRITER.

I want to design Document class as below.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class document
{
@Id
private int id;
@Column
private String name;

private List<DocumentUser> readers;

private List<DocumentUser> writers;
}
```

Please guide me how can i map the "readers" and "writers" in above class such that i can get the list of them when select a document.

Thanks.

Comment: Can a reader become a writer (or vice-versa)?

Comment: You want to set up the `Reader` and `Writer` in a class hierarchy of `Document User` then use the http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperclass system.

Comment: @JBNizet: Writer would be a reader by default. Yes Reader can become writer.

Answer (score 0):

I would make things simple, and simply have one mapped collection of DocumentUser. Getting the writers would just return a filtered collection. Ditto for getting the readers which are not writers:

```
public List<DocumentUser> getWriters() {
    List<DocumentUser> result = new ArrayList<DocumentUser>();
    for (DocumentUser du : documentUsers) {
        if (du.getRole() == DocumentUserRole.WRITER) {
            result.add(du);
        }
    }
    return du;
}
```

This has the advantage of being very close to the reality of the database design. It doesn't need any implementation-specific trick. And it allows transforming a reader into a writer by just doing `documentUser.setRole(DocumentUserRole.WRITER)`, without needing to remove the user from a list and adding it to the other.

An inheritance-based solution would have been appropriate if the type of the DocumentUser was known from the beginning, and would never change.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it won't get automatically load my list of readers and writers when i select the document. I need to call this method. What exactly i want is when i load the document it will prefill the list.

Comment: toMany associations are lazy-loaded by default. When it'll be loaded, the `documentUsers` list will be populated. And when you call getWriters(), it will lazy-load the `documentUsers` list, and return only the users which are writers. I don't really see where the problem is.